# Is correct this boot procedure in HPUX?

Tags: boot, hp-ux

I'm studyng hp-ux and unix in general.
I'm a little confused about isl ipl and pdc. 
As I know, 
pdc on hppa is the same thing as a bios on x86
make a post and load bootloader
bootloader are two,ipl which loads isl which load
hpux kernel.
Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Booting a HP-9000 system takes 3 steps.

Imagine you reset or power on the machine.

#### Step 1

`PDC` = Processor Dependent Code (self-test, initialize processor, peripherals,..) is loaded from ROM.

#### Step 2

`ISL` = Initial System Loader

#### Step3

The `hpux` loads the HP-UX `kernel` and hands over control to the kernel.

The kernel then starts the `swapper` process and then `init`.

### Glossary

`IPL` = Initial Program Load, originally used on IBM mainframes, nowadays another term for "booting".